# How do I know what languages compile to ARMv7hl?

Tags: rust, sailfish-os, mer

I would like to program SailfishOS applications. But, I would prefer not to use QML, C++, or Python.

I'd like to use something like Rust. But, I'm not sure how to know what options I really have.

What kind of things should I know to be able to determine what compilers will create binaries for ARMv7hl?

Answer (score 1):

You can't really avoid Qt, but with C++ that trick is possible.
There was a thread on [Devel mailing list](https://lists.sailfishos.org/pipermail/devel/2015-August/006389.html). All you need is to find good Qt5 bindings for Rust. [These](https://github.com/cyndis/qmlrs) look promising.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use *any* QML and C++, [the answer is probably no](https://together.jolla.com/question/78324/questionpure-c-sailfish-documentation/). But if you fancy writing some kind of wrapper like [pyotherside](http://thp.io/2011/pyotherside/), it seems doable.